.NET -> how to make API with nested Objects?
Is there any tutorial in .NET how to make the following API structure in which will [HttpPost] DestinationPlan to the database (with nested object of DestinationPlanDays - Destinations - SubDestinations) :

DestinationPlan -> List of DestinationPlanDays
DestinationPlanDay -> Date, DayNumber, List of Destinations
Destination -> ID, Name, EstimatedTime, List of SubDestinations
SubDestination -> Name

PS. I am new to .net, so I would need more beginner-friendly explanation. Thanks.
I've created domain Models using the following structure (+/-):
namespace Itinerary.API.Models.Domain
{
    public class DestinationPlan
    {

        public List<DestinationPlanDay> DestinationPlanDays { get; set; }
    }
}


According to your requirement, here is the tutorial for you.
1. MyDbContext.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using WebApplication4.Areas.Identity.Data;
using WebApplication4.Models.Domain;

namespace WebApplication4.Areas.Identity.Data;

public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyApplicationUser>
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<DestinationPlan> DestinationPlans { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DestinationPlanDay> DestinationPlanDays { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubDestination> SubDestinations { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<DestinationPlan>().ToTable("DestinationPlans");
        builder.Entity<DestinationPlanDay>().ToTable("DestinationPlanDays");
        builder.Entity<Destination>().ToTable("Destinations");
        builder.Entity<SubDestination>().ToTable("SubDestinations");

        builder.Entity<DestinationPlanDay>()
                .HasOne<DestinationPlan>()
                .WithMany(dp => dp.DestinationPlanDays)
                .HasForeignKey(dpd => dpd.DestinationPlanId);

        builder.Entity<Destination>()
            .HasOne<DestinationPlanDay>()
            .WithMany(dpd => dpd.Destinations)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DestinationPlanDayId);

        builder.Entity<SubDestination>()
            .HasOne<Destination>()
            .WithMany(d => d.SubDestinations)
            .HasForeignKey(sd => sd.DestinationId);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

2. Models/Domain/Destination.cs
namespace WebApplication4.Models.Domain
{
    public class Destination
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan EstimatedTime { get; set; }

        public int DestinationPlanDayId { get; set; }
        public List<SubDestination>? SubDestinations { get; set; }
    }
}

3. Models/Domain/DestinationPlan.cs
namespace WebApplication4.Models.Domain
{
    public class DestinationPlan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<DestinationPlanDay>? DestinationPlanDays { get; set; }
    }
}

4. Models/Domain/DestinationPlanDay.cs
namespace WebApplication4.Models.Domain
{
    public class DestinationPlanDay
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int DayNumber { get; set; }

        public int DestinationPlanId { get; set; }
        public List<Destination>? Destinations { get; set; }
    }
}

5. Models/Domain/SubDestination.cs
namespace WebApplication4.Models.Domain
{
    public class SubDestination
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    }
}

6. DestinationPlansController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication4.Areas.Identity.Data;
using WebApplication4.Models.Domain;

namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class DestinationPlansController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DestinationPlansController> _logger;
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public DestinationPlansController(ILogger<DestinationPlansController> logger, MyDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostDestinationPlan([FromBody]DestinationPlan destinationPlan)
        {
            if (destinationPlan.DestinationPlanDays != null)
            {
                foreach (var day in destinationPlan.DestinationPlanDays)
                {
                    day.Id = 0;
                    if (day.Destinations != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var destination in day.Destinations)
                        {
                            destination.Id = 0;
                            if (destination.SubDestinations != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var subDestination in destination.SubDestinations)
                                {
                                    subDestination.Id = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            _context.DestinationPlans.Add(destinationPlan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetDestinationPlan), new { id = destinationPlan.Id }, destinationPlan);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetDestinationPlan(int id)
        {
            var destinationPlan = await _context.DestinationPlans
                .Include(dp => dp.DestinationPlanDays)
                    .ThenInclude(dpd => dpd.Destinations)
                        .ThenInclude(d => d.SubDestinations)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(dp => dp.Id == id);

            if (destinationPlan == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(destinationPlan);
        }
    }
}

7. Migrations
Add-Migration 'Init' -Context 'MyDbContext'
Update-Database -Context 'MyDbContext'

8. Test and Result
https://localhost:7268/DestinationPlans/PostDestinationPlan
Body
    {
  "destinationPlanDays": [
    {
      "date": "2024-07-01T00:00:00",
      "dayNumber": 1,
      "destinations": [
        {
          "name": "Destination 1",
          "estimatedTime": "02:00:00",
          "subDestinations": [
            {
              "name": "SubDestination 1-1"
            },
            {
              "name": "SubDestination 1-2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Destination 2",
          "estimatedTime": "03:00:00",
          "subDestinations": [
            {
              "name": "SubDestination 2-1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2024-07-02T00:00:00",
      "dayNumber": 2,
      "destinations": [
        {
          "name": "Destination 3",
          "estimatedTime": "01:30:00",
          "subDestinations": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}




I will try to implement it to see whether it works and if it works, I will accept you answer. Thank you in advance.
PS: is it openAI generated ?

Hi @PiotrDeja, openAi maybe can guide us how to implement this  feature I think, but I am not sure. All the codes above are based from my exprence, by the way, in my post method, I am using FromBody, you can change it according to your needs, something like FromForm.

Hi @PiotrDeja If you need further help, please let me know.

OK, I will inform you when I need help, I had a busy week at work :P

Ok, finally I have the time to do this. This is my current setup.
ApplicationDbContext:
using Itinerary.API.Models.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Itinerary.API.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DestinationPlan> DestinationPlan { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DestinationPlanDay> DestinationPlanDays { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubDestination> SubDestinations { get; set; }
    }
}

Models/Domain/DestinationPlan.cs:
namespace Itinerary.API.Models.Domain
{
    public class DestinationPlan
    {

        public List<DestinationPlanDay> DestinationPlanDays { get; set; }
    }

}

Models/Domain/DestinationPlanDay.cs:
namespace Itinerary.API.Models.Domain
{
    public class DestinationPlanDay
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int DayNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
    }

}

Models/Domain/DestinationPlanDay.cs:
namespace Itinerary.API.Models.Domain
{
    public class Destination
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EstimatedTime { get; set; }
        public List<SubDestination> SubDestinations { get; set; }
    }

}

Models/Domain/SubDestination.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Itinerary.API.Models.Domain
{
    public class SubDestination
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    }
}

DestinationPlanController:
namespace Itinerary.API.Controllers
{
    // https://localhost:xxxx/api/destination_plan
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DestinationPlanController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

        public DestinationPlanController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        //
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDestinationPlan(CreateDestinationPlanRequestDto request)
        {
            // Map DTO to Domain Model
            var destinationPlan = new DestinationPlan
            {
                DestinationPlanDays = (List<DestinationPlanDay>)request.destinationPlanDay
            };

            await dbContext.DestinationPlan.AddAsync(destinationPlan);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Domain model to DTO
            var response = new DestinationPlanDto
            {
                DestinationPlanDay = destinationPlan.DestinationPlanDays,
            };

            return Ok(response);
        }

    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
